AspNet Core Razor Pages app with Keycloak in docker
I am trying to configure an AspNet Core Web App (Razor Pages) with Keycloak (25.0.5) and Docker.
My setup includes (in docker compose file)

a postgres container
a keycloak container
a container for my AspNet Core application

This is the configuration of keycloak and app in docker compose
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev
    environment:
      - <omitted for brevity>
    ports:
      - "9001:8080"
  web-portal:
    container_name: web-portal
    image: ghcr.io/myapp/web-portal:latest
    ports:
      - "9101:8080"

With this configuration I am able to access from the browser (on the host)

keycloak admin at http://localhost:9001
my application at http://localhost:9101

I have created a realm on Keycloak and a client in the realm. The realm has no Frontend URL attribute set and has myrealm as Realm ID.
The client has the following configuration:



Key
Value




Client ID
web-portal-client


Valid Redirect URIs
http://localhost:9101/signin-oidc


Valid post logout redirect URIs
http://localhost:9101/signout-callback-oidc


Web Origins
*


Client Authentication
On


Authorization
On


Standard Flow
Checked


Direct access grants
Checked



If I launch the portal on my machine (e.g. in debug from the code editor) everything works very fine. The problem arise when I publish my AspNet web application in docker.
To configure the web application I am using quite a standard code block which used to work fine with duende identity server
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
        options.Cookie.Name = "CookieName";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = $"http://localhost:9001/realms/myrealm";
        options.MetadataAddress = $http://keycloak:8080/realms/myrealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.ClientId = "web-portal-client";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });

As found somewhere on the internet I added the configuration of MetadataAddress to explicitly avoid the docker container using localhost.
However when it comes to redirect to the Authorization endpoint the generated URL is like this one
http://keycloak:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=web-portal-client&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9101%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&code_challenge=xxx&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxx&state=xxx&x-client-SKU=ID_NET8_0&x-client-ver=7.5.1.0
which can not be accessed by the browser on the host.
Any suggestion on how to get the problem solved?
